# Docker CLI in Freestyle Build Shell

Tags: jenkins, docker, cloudbees

I'd like to run the postgres docker image instead of the postgres binary provided by cloudbees due to the lack of uuid and postgis support. However, the only two docker plugins I have access to are *CloudBees Docker Custom Build Environment Plugin* and *Docker Commons Plugin*. I'd like to avoid the extra complexity associated with the custom build env plugin due to the need to setup docker in docker(outer image for the slave and inner image for postgres).

Comment: The question is very unclear. Is this in reference to a Jenkins build defined on CloudBees’ DEV@cloud service? If so, there is no Docker support available currently.

Comment: Yes this is regarding DEV@cloud.